# Check if a number has same digit in Python

Tags: python

How to check if a number has same digit in Python

**For example:**

`check(111) --> True`

`check(22) --> True`

`check(111) --> True`

`check(45) --> False`

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem on your side?

Comment: @HampusLarsson Please wait let me update the question

Comment: hi ,  i see you are not new  please follow this step before asking https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what would be the output of `check(112)`?

Comment: Or what about `check(121)`?

Comment: @khelwood False

Comment: @Ch3steR False..

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28365

Comment: @Ch3steR Seriously man? Please read that question carefully. Check whether all numbers are unique. For example `1234` --> True `1124` --> False.

Comment: @Ch3steR But in my Question, `1124` ---> False and even `1234` --> False

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer You just need to change one alphabet in that and replace it with `1`. Come on man you do that yourself. That's the reason I called it possible duplicate not exact duplicate.

Comment: `lambda n:len(set(str(n)))==1` that's it see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212838/discussion-between-newbieprogrammer-and-ch3ster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you expecting an answer like this? It will return True if all the digits are same else False.

What I am doing in this answer is, I am taking the first digit then I am multiplying the string form of the digit times the length of the string and using an If statement to check whether they match or not.

```py
def check(n):
    if str(n) == str(n)[0] * len(str(n)):
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(check(45))
```

Comment: Yes, yes that's what I am talking about. Thank you very much :)